# NoReverseMatch error when using summernote in Django

Tags: django, summernote

When I clicked the add button in django admin to add some articles, the error happened. Some details are shown below.

debug info

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/guitar/article/add/
Reverse for 'django_summernote-editor' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 'id_content'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$summernote/editor/(?P<id>.+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/guitar/article/add/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'django_summernote-editor' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 'id_content'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$summernote/editor/(?P<id>.+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 495
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['D:\\DemoGuitarProject',
 'D:\\DemoGuitarProject',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 14 Nov 2015 16:45:05 +0800
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19
Reverse for 'django_summernote-editor' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 'id_content'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$summernote/editor/(?P<id>.+)/$']
9               {% for field in line %}
10                  <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
11                      {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
12                      {% if field.is_checkbox %}
13                          {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
14                      {% else %}
15                          {{ field.label_tag }}
16                          {% if field.is_readonly %}
17                              <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
18                          {% else %}
19  

      {{ field.field }}



20                          {% endif %}
21                      {% endif %}
22                      {% if field.field.help_text %}
23                          <p class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>
24                      {% endif %}
25                  </div>
26              {% endfor %}
27          </div>
28      {% endfor %}
29  </fieldset>
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for DemoGuitarProject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os



BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)



MEDIA_URL = "media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")




# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ')7sn#y%9dgm!pxl#c$ws_jld!%2lbvj5tg*jlqnaelc)+$bp*%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'guitar',
    'django_summernote',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DemoGuitarProject.urls'



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DemoGuitarProject.wsgi.application'



# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', 'guitar.views.home', name='home'),


    url(r'^summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),

]
```

admins.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article, Category


from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin
class SomeModelAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    pass



admin.site.register(Article,SomeModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

models.py

```
# coding:utf-8

from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db import models




class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(u'标题', max_length=256)
    content = models.TextField(u'内容')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(u'发表时间', auto_now_add=True, editable=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(u'更新时间',auto_now=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title      



class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are including the above urls, make sure that they don't end in a dollar.

For example, instead of

```
url(r'^guitar/$', include('guitar.urls')),
```

It should be

```
url(r'^guitar/', include('guitar.urls')),
```

Comment: wow~It works. This really helps me a lot! Thanks for your help. ^_^